# looking to add a button for my dnd group (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to add a button to make a towns profit added to a sheet per session I looked on an older post and I am trying to make the button for it the function I'm using doesn't seem to be working

I get an error message:

> Script function function increment() { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F1').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F1').getValue() + 1); } could not be found

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD6q8.png)

[image]

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

Put your function in Google Apps Script, accessed in menu `Tools -> Script Editor`, save it, then assign the function name to the button.

The first time you click the button you will have to authorize your sheet.

[image]

[image]